# Easy way to get the 'They're Not Dolls...' and '...They're Action Figures' achievements

Tags: achievements, fallout-4, cheats

Is there another way, than collecting 20 bobbleheads, to get the achievement 'They're Not Dolls...' and '...They're Action Figures'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open a text editor such as notepad.exe, paste the following lines and save it as `bobbleheads.txt` in `.\Steam\steamapps\common\Fallout 4`.

In the game, open the console and enter `bat bobbleheads`.

All 20 bobbleheads will be placed at your feet. Pick them up and earn both achievements.

```
player.placeatme 00178b63
player.placeatme 00178b5d
player.placeatme 00178b55
player.placeatme 00178b54
player.placeatme 00178b58
player.placeatme 00178b51
player.placeatme 00178b5a
player.placeatme 00178b52
player.placeatme 00178b53
player.placeatme 00178b56
player.placeatme 00178b57
player.placeatme 00178b59
player.placeatme 00178b5b
player.placeatme 00178b5c
player.placeatme 00178b5e
player.placeatme 00178b5f
player.placeatme 00178b60
player.placeatme 00178b61
player.placeatme 00178b62
player.placeatme 00178b64
```

Comment: Oh My!!! That's cheating !!! :-)